# Wordpress Media Photos loaded but not appearing

Tags: wordpress, upload, media, photos

In my media library there are no photos appearing, but when I click on the individual file to edit the photo it appears.  When I click on show attachment page on my website, the photo does not appear.

I'm trying to use the revolution slider but it is in wordpress that there is the issue it appears

Comment: They aren't any error message, or details?

Comment: please define "the photo does not appear." Is it showing a 404 or 500 error?  If 500, it could be permissions related.  I had a similar problem on a Windows server that could not show the file I uploaded but could show the thumbnails that Wordpress generated based on that file.

Comment: Thank you, in the backend of wordpress it is not appearing in the thumbnail of the thumbnail library gallery or the load image gallery when I try to create a slide.  The slider is working fine because when I insert text it appears and all of the tranistions are there everything seems fine with the js etc.  It is the media library not producing the images.

When I click on edit image link from the media library thumnbnail view and the upload image from media library area (also thumbndails) it shows the image just fine on the edit image page from the backend.

Comment: when I create the slide as if its just a normal slide that you just cant see the thumbnail, it still doesnt appear on the frontside in the slide.  Maybe some code got messed up or maybe I have a conflicting plugin for the media somehow.

All input is appareciated

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this after the hoster messed up my permissions on a server upgrade. Tried all the usual like:

- disabling all plugins
- changing themes
- changing/resaving permalinks
- deleting/renaming .htaccess

Nothing worked. The images were showing up only on the Edit media page (Media/Edit/Edit image). Whel loading site, the response for the for the images given by browser was ranging from 404 Not found to 301 Moved permanently, depending on permalink settings.
So, after trying all above, try to:

- change uploads folder and subfolders permissions to 755.
- change all files inside uploads folder permissions to 644.

Pay attention when changing files permissions, to check that they actually change, and if not:

- download and reupload all the content of the uploads folder

The last operation was the one that solved the problem for me.